# How do (or can) I make live code changes to Angular SSR Universal app?

Tags: angular, universal

I am coming to Angular Universal from dev with Next.js and Razzle.js (both SSR HMR frameworks) and I want to make live changes to a universal SSR app. Is there a way to configure a Universal app to configure HMR and SSR together?

Presently I can't make ANY changes to my source code without stopping the server and re-running "npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr". This is an awkward slow developer experience compared to Razzle and Next which just work and give lightning page loads with SSR and HMR.

At the very least I would like to see content changes when I reload the page in the browser without a full rebuild. Even better would be live changes without page reload.

I'm quite new to Angular 8. Am I just being too naive/hopeful to want to achieve this with Angular 8 Universal?

Comment: Not naive at all, we’ve been asking for this for quite a while: https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1022 - the good news; it’s coming soon!

Comment: that is great news! thanks.